# Make a faster search of folders

Tags: c#

Recently with the precious help of some forum users i have developed a search application of folders and subfolders. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Procura_Desenhos
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public static List<string> pathsToFind = new List<string>();

        private void txt_procura_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void btn_procura_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string originalPath = @"c:\";
            string findPath = txt_procura.Text;

            FolderNames(originalPath);

            List<string> paths = pathsToFind;

            IEnumerable<string> filteredPaths = paths.Where(x => x.Remove(0,x.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) == findPath);

            foreach (string path in filteredPaths)
            {
                 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new             System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    FileName = "explorer.exe",
                    Arguments = path,
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                    Verb = "open"
                });
            }
        }
        public static void FolderNames(string path)
        {

            pathsToFind.Add(path);

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo info in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    FolderNames(info.FullName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

However the path C: it was only for testing (var root = new DirectoryInfo (@ "C: \");) the goal is that the application search folders on a local server (var root = new DirectoryInfo (@ "\ vgst \ clients \ ");).

Inside the folder clients there are hundreds and hundreds of subdirectories with a unique ID that is not repeated, this ID is the reference sale.

Already tested and the application works, however is very slow in searching, sometimes takes several minutes to open the folder that we sent to search.

**Is there any way to accelerate this search?**

Thanks again.

Comment: Doing the search on the server itself would speed things up.

Comment: Try using the bare bones Win32 API, it might be faster, but don't expect large folder structures to be returned fast when done over the network.

Comment: How i  implement  Win32 API in my code?

Comment: IO.Directory.GetDirectories( ) returns an array of found folder names - why are you using Explorer?

Comment: Side note: Avoid pokémon exception handling (google that).

Comment: rheitzman i use explorer to open and explorer that folder.

Comment: Could you cache the result between uses of the app? Google's Picasa is doing that, caching thumbnails of found images, so that it doesn't have to constantly crawl the monitored folders.

Comment: I'd suggest you use GetFolders() for the portion of the tree you are searching (not C:\ - you won't have access to all folders) to populate a list one time. Then for each subsequent search for the session use a LINQ query to search the list. This will avoid repeated calls to the file system. 
No need to use FileInfo you already have the path. 
FYI Process.Start(<path>) works to open explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to speed this sort of thing up in the past and I've never gotten anywhere--profiling shows that most of the time isn't spent in my code anyway.  There's not much you can do to an IO-bound process other than keep the IO clean.

One thing that goes badly--threading.  Don't try to use multiple threads to read more than one directory at once--yes, you get to use the other CPU cores but you cause the head to bounce around more, the end result is slower.  (Note that I have **not** tested this on a SSD, the results very well might be different!)

The two things I have found that do produce performance gains **in some cases** is to use threading to do additional processing of the data and to use the low level API for file finding if I needed more than just names.